# Arguments of a function

Tags: java, function, arguments

I need a function with more arguments as:

```
private GroupLayout function(Container host, Class J1, String nameofJ1, Class J2, String nameofJ2,..................Class Jn, String nameofJn) {
//body
}
```

a fuction for a customizable Grouplayout for use in more applications.

I tried:

```
private GroupLayout function(Container host, Class ...arg, String ...arg1) {
    //body
}
but didn't work, it said "varargs parameter must be the last parameter, and with class are some problems.
```

for example, I'd like a function call as:
function(NamePanel, JButton, "xxx", JMenu, "yyy", JComboBox, "zzz") and to former a GroupLayout on NamePanel with JButton named "xxx", JMenu named "yyy" and so one.

Is somebody who knows a solve of this problema?

Comment: Your use case is too vague for specific help, but sounds like perhaps you're looking for a `Map<Class, String>`.

Comment: It's about only call a function

Comment: Class ...arg and String ...arg1 are both variable args. You can only have one variable arg and it has to be at the end of a method parameter list. Having so many arguments in a method is actually bad design, you should rethink your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Varargs**

You cannot use varargs more than once. Why? The compiler will be clueless what parameters you pass in.

See the example using `String` only where the compiler the first parameter is a `String` and the rest (0..n) is vararg (compiled into an array):

```
static void function(String arg, String ...arg1) { }                    // COMPILES
```

```
// this is perfectly valid, the first one is 'arg' and the rest is 'arg1'
function("1", "2", "3");
```

This one with multiple varargs doesn't work, as long as the compiler doesn't know where `arg1` ends and `arg2` starts:

```
static void function(String arg, String ...arg1, String ...arg2) { }    // DOESN'T COMPILE
```

```
// are both "2" and "3" an 'arg1' and 'arg2' is empty or different?
function("1", "2", "3");
```

For this reason, varargs must be **always** the **last** formal parameter.

**Workaround**

You seem want to pass a pair of `Class` and `String`. The best way to pass these pairs is to use a key-value based structure `Map<Class, String>` which also guarantees the same number of keys and values is equal.

```
private GroupLayout function(Container host, Map<Class<?>, String> classStringMap) {
    // method body
}
```

```
Map<Class<?>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(J1.class, "name of J1");
map.put(J2.class, "name of J2");
...
function(container, map);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is your friend.

This is [java builder implementation](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern).

Look at [Lombok Builder annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder) as well.